# screen flickering **i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun: transcoder,** issue

Tags: drivers, gnome, intel, i915

I am having Screen flickering issue on my ubuntu laptop.

I was getting **i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun: transcoder,** issue

please anyone help me to fix this issue.

I have tried **i915.enable_psr=0 i915.fastboot=0** but nothing works.

```markdown
$ inxi -b
System:
  Host: User Kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: TIMI product: Mi NoteBook Ultra v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: TIMI model: TM2017 v: V44K1 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: TIMI
    v: RMATG5B0P0D0D date: 07/14/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 33.9 Wh (54.6%) condition: 62.1/70.0 Wh (88.7%)
    volts: 15.4 min: 15.4
CPU:
  Info: quad core 11th Gen Intel Core i5-11300H [MT MCP] speed (MHz):
    avg: 965 min/max: 400/4400
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Sunplus Innovation XiaoMi USB 2.0 Webcam type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting
    gpu: i915 resolution: 3200x2000~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 232.67 GiB (48.8%)
Info:
  Processes: 379 Uptime: 32m Memory: 7.55 GiB used: 5.77 GiB (76.4%)
  Shell: Zsh inxi: 3.3.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on laptop Chuwi GemiBook.
My workarounds are:

1. work with ubuntu kernel 5.15.0-39
2. work with ubuntu kernel 5.15.0-46 and set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.enable_psr=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"` into `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: even after I've set it to max_cstate=4 still happens (laptop connected to docking station)

Comment: I have tried this but still I am getting the same issue.